# Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence xml transformation exception

Tags: java, xml, xslt, encoding

I'm trying to transform some xml files which are us-ascii encoded
The transformer works fine with utf-8/iso-8859-1 but not with us-ascii.
I also tried using `FileInputStream` method but not sure if you have specify any encoding on the `StreamResult` part

Here is my code:

```
    File xsl = new File("src/xsl/prism.xsl");
    String fname = file.getName();

    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Source xslt = new StreamSource(xsl);

    try{

        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "us-ascii");
        Source text = new StreamSource(file.getCanonicalFile());

        System.out.println("Transformed "  + fname + "\n");
        transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File(outPath + file.getName())));


    }catch (TransformerException | IOException e) {

        System.out.println("Error in: "+fname+"\n");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Here are the exceptions being thrown:

```
   com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.XSLTCDTMManager.getDTM(XSLTCDTMManager.java:464)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.XSLTCDTMManager.getDTM(XSLTCDTMManager.java:252)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getDOM(TransformerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:748)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:359)
    at com.rogers.ramraja.XSLT.transform(XSLT.java:66)
    at com.rogers.ramraja.XSLT.main(XSLT.java:41)
---------
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(UTF8Reader.java:687)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:408)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1728)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipChar(XMLEntityScanner.java:1400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2823)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.XSLTCDTMManager.getDTM(XSLTCDTMManager.java:458)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.XSLTCDTMManager.getDTM(XSLTCDTMManager.java:252)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getDOM(TransformerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:748)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:359)
    at com.rogers.ramraja.XSLT.transform(XSLT.java:66)
    at com.rogers.ramraja.XSLT.main(XSLT.java:41)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs when the transformer tries to load your source XML document. It tries to read it using UTF-8 encoding (UTF-8 is the default if there is no XML declaration or the declaration does not contain an encoding attribute).

Apparently the error is thrown because the source file is not properly encoded in UTF-8.

Now any file encoded in 7-bit-ASCII is also a valid UTF-8. Therefore it follows that your source document must not be a 7-bit-ASCII file.

Comment: I did a file -I (I'm on a MAC) on the file and it showed it's charset as us-ascii. Is there a certain way the transformer must be configured to transform. I did specify us-ascii as one of the settings though. Thanks!

Comment: `file -l` may not be a reliable way to detect the encoding. Can you show the file in your question?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1XJsfPMrrrtMmJEbVlCY2hEUVk/view here is a sample.